Run mgcv package in python via rpy2
I am trying to create a python package to run mgcv in R, to replace the functionality of pyGAM. I want to start with the r command gam(), and need to use rpy2 to transfer data from R. I don't know how to define the command in python to encapsulate the functionality of running the gam command from r (mainly to simplify the python code), and I am trying to understand some of the functions of the pymer4 package on how data is transferred between the two languages.
I don't have a lot of experience with developing packages and I'd like to understand a little bit about how these functions are defined

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
